# Node.js setImmediate v8 context

Tags: node.js

Code in concern:

```
const vm = require('vm');
const message = require('./messaging.js');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const addon = message.load('addon');

var obj = new addon.MyObject(10);
var sb = new addon.SandBox();
var out = 0;

obj.on('plused', (a)=> { console.log('plused:', a, out++);});
sb.on('added', (a)=> { console.log('added', a, out++);});

sb.add("obj1", obj);
sb.add("obj2", obj);
sb.add("console", console);

console.log(obj.value()); 

var script = new vm.Script("obj1.plusOne(); obj2.plusOne();");

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  const context = new vm.createContext(sb);
  script.runInContext(context);
}


console.log(obj.value());
```

---

The `plusOne` and `add` functions emit events through a function in messaging.js, which is being postponed by using `setImmediate` call.

For object `sb`, `setImmediate` is being called from the main context, and for object `obj`, it's being called from the context created in the for loop.

There is no doubt that for `sb`, and the event is fired, and handled all in the same context.

For the `obj` case, the event is fired from a new context other than the main context, and I reckon the handler should be executed in the same context where the event was emited, therefore it would have no access to the object `out` in main context.

However the code runs well, in both case, `out` in the main context is accessed. It looks that the callback function of `setImmediate` is always executed on the main context.

Please explain why this is the case, thank you.

---

The output:

```
10
16
added obj1 0
added obj2 1
added console 2
plused: 11 3
plused: 12 4
plused: 13 5
plused: 14 6
plused: 15 7
plused: 16 8
```